# Unexpected token on response.writeHead

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, fs

When running the following code in Node.JS it produces some error but I cant understand why

```
var http = require("http"), fs = require("fs");

function onRequest(request, response){
        request.on("end", function(){
                fs.readFile("test.txt", "utf-8", function(error, data){
                        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type", "text/plain"});
                        data = parseInt(data) + 1;
                        fs.writeFile('test.txt', data);
                        response.end("This page was refreshed "+data+" times!\n");
                });
        });
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8080);
```

Here are the errors I get:

```
/home/dev/nodeplay/files.js:7

response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type", "text-plain"});
                  ^
module.js:434
  var compiledWrapper = runInThisContext(wrapper, filename, true);
                        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:25)
    at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:484:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:190:38)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This part: `{"Content-Type", "text-plain"}` is an invalid object.

Do you mean:

```
{"Content-Type": "text-plain"}
```